# Packer waiting for SSH to become available

Tags: vagrant, packer

I am new to packer and vagrant and I am trying to build a brand new Windows OS Virtual box from Windows 10 disc image and packer. However, while doing build, packer never quits on the step `"Waiting for SSH to become available"`. I have tried and followed multiple solutions from Stack overflow and Hashicorp but nothing fixed my issue.

My windows 10 JSON file:

```
{
  "builders": [
    {
      "type": "virtualbox-iso",
      "iso_url": "{{user `iso_url`}}",
      "iso_checksum_type": "{{user `iso_checksum_type`}}",
      "iso_checksum": "{{user `iso_checksum`}}",
      "headless": false,
      "boot_wait": "10m",
      "ssh_username": "vagrant",
      "ssh_password": "vagrant",
      "ssh_wait_timeout": "2h",
      "shutdown_command": "shutdown /s /t 10 /f /d p:4:1 /c \"Packer Shutdown\"",
      "guest_os_type": "Windows10_64",
      "disk_size": 61440,
      "vboxmanage": [
        [
          "modifyvm",
          "{{.Name}}",
          "--memory",
          "2048"
        ],
        [
          "modifyvm",
          "{{.Name}}",
          "--cpus",
          "2"
        ]
      ]
    }
  ],
  "post-processors":[
    {
      "type": "vagrant",
      "keep_input_artifact": false,
      "output": "windows_10_{{.Provider}}.box",
      "vagrantfile_template": "windows10.template"
    }
  ],
  "variables": {
    "iso_url": "C:/Ebe/Vagrant/Windows_10/SW_DVD5_Win_Pro_10_1511.1_64BIT_English_MLF_X20-93914.iso",
    "iso_checksum_type": "md5",
    "iso_checksum": "bd09dc56c51a6ce137b8c0eb7c4369ea",
    "autounattend": "./answer_files/10/Autounattend.xml"
  }
}
```

My windows.template

```
Vagrant.require_version ">= 1.6.2"

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
    config.vm.define "vagrant-windows-10"
    config.vm.box = "windows_10"
    config.vm.communicator = "winrm"

    # Admin user name and password
    config.winrm.username = "vagrant"
    config.winrm.password = "vagrant"   config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.56.1"

    config.vm.guest = :windows
    config.windows.halt_timeout = 15

    config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 3389, host: 3389, id: "rdp", auto_correct: true
    config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 22, host: 2222, id: "ssh", auto_correct: true

    config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |v, override|
        #v.gui = true
        v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", 2048]
        v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--cpus", 2]
        v.customize ["setextradata", "global", "GUI/SuppressMessages", "all" ]
    end

    config.vm.provider :vmware_fusion do |v, override|
        #v.gui = true
        v.vmx["memsize"] = "2048"
        v.vmx["numvcpus"] = "2"
        v.vmx["ethernet0.virtualDev"] = "vmxnet3"
        v.vmx["RemoteDisplay.vnc.enabled"] = "false"
        v.vmx["RemoteDisplay.vnc.port"] = "5900"
        v.vmx["scsi0.virtualDev"] = "lsisas1068"
    end

    config.vm.provider :vmware_workstation do |v, override|
        #v.gui = true
        v.vmx["memsize"] = "2048"
        v.vmx["numvcpus"] = "2"
        v.vmx["ethernet0.virtualDev"] = "vmxnet3"
        v.vmx["RemoteDisplay.vnc.enabled"] = "false"
        v.vmx["RemoteDisplay.vnc.port"] = "5900"

        v.vmx["scsi0.virtualDev"] = "lsisas1068"
    end end
```

I am using below command to kick off the build

```
packer build windows10.json
```

Below is the output of never ending build

```
virtualbox-iso output will be in this color.

==> virtualbox-iso: Downloading or copying Guest additions
    virtualbox-iso: Downloading or copying: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Oracle/VirtualBox/VBoxGuestAdditions.iso
==> virtualbox-iso: Downloading or copying ISO
    virtualbox-iso: Downloading or copying: file:///C:/Ebe/Vagrant/Windows_10/SW_DVD5_Win_Pro_10_1511.1_64BIT_English_MLF_X20-93914.iso
==> virtualbox-iso: Creating virtual machine...
==> virtualbox-iso: Creating hard drive...
==> virtualbox-iso: Creating forwarded port mapping for communicator (SSH, WinRM, etc) (host port 3527)
==> virtualbox-iso: Executing custom VBoxManage commands...
    virtualbox-iso: Executing: modifyvm packer-virtualbox-iso-1499123943 --memory 2048
    virtualbox-iso: Executing: modifyvm packer-virtualbox-iso-1499123943 --cpus 2
==> virtualbox-iso: Starting the virtual machine...
==> virtualbox-iso: Waiting 10m0s for boot...
==> virtualbox-iso: Typing the boot command...
==> virtualbox-iso: Waiting for SSH to become available...
```

Please let me know if you have any suggestion to make this build work.

Comment: whats your virtual box version ?

Comment: my virtual box is of version **5.1.20 r114628**

Comment: I have the same issue. I installed OpenSSH on my machine (not the VM) and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Installing Windows automatically is a complicated matter. Instead of starting from scratch I recommend that you base your work on someone else, for example https://github.com/joefitzgerald/packer-windows

One basic problem with your packer template is that it should use WinRM and not SSH.

Comment: Thanks Rickard, its a POC I am doing in my company, where they want to create base windows image for multiple projects, so I have to install from company given OS version.  I see the difference in windows template and JSON.. so I have winrm in template and ssh in JSON file. do you think it is causing this issue?

Comment: Yes and that you don't have `Autounattended.xml` on a floppy etc. Get the linked version running first and the replace with your iso and adapt.

Comment: Rickard, can you elaborate on this point "Get the linked version running first and the replace with your iso and adapt". Thanks

Comment: I provided a link to a repository in my answer with working templates. Take one of those, the one closest to what you want. Change it in small steps and verify that it still works between each step.

Comment: I get what you are saying now, my current template and json file are the modified version of the files available in the above link. Initially when i tried those template with out any modification, it errored at "floppy_files" section and subsequent scripts. I am searching for the ways to create `autounattend.xml` for Windows10 OS.

Comment: Im actually using the win10 template from packer-windows and Im also getting "waiting for SSH..."